# Laravel 5 remember me not working

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5, session-cookies

I am unable to get `Laravel` **rememeber me** functionality to work.

I added remember token column to my `User` Model table.
My `User` Model `Authenticatable`. User model doesn't contain anything else specific related to remember me functionality

I am using default Auth drivers and guard.

My `Usercontroller` is different from default one. It extends from `Controller`. It doesn't use any Traits. In my login method, I use `Auth::login($userModelObject, true)` to login user. Everything works fine. Remember me token gets updated in database. I can see 3 cookies on browser `XSRF-TOKEN`, `laravel_session`, `remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d`.

`Auth::check()` returns true as expected but if I either remove, expires, or modify `laravel_session`, in the subsequent request, `remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d` cookie also gets removed for some reason (I am not able to view it using `var_dump($_COOKIE)` in only middleware I applied) and I think that's why Laravel Auth driver isn't able to use remember me Cookie to autologin user. CSRF middleware is also being applied automatically by Framework.

What could be causing this behaviour? Do I need to use some Additional Traits on my User Model or Controller?

Note: I am using Laravel 5.4 and my session config are:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 20,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'store' => null,
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
'http_only' => true
```

Comment: Why would you remove, expires, or modify laravel_session cookie? I don't think this is how remember me works.

Comment: Just to test remember me functionality. Isn't this what it do? To persist user login and use remember token when normal user session has expired?

Comment: Yes dude, my bad. deleting laravel_session does not log out.

Comment: I found the problem. I had this `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` in Kernel.php. I compared my project with new laravel 5.4 project and found that this is commented out by default. I did that and my problem is fixed now.

Comment: Post it as an answer and mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I had this \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class in Kernel.php. I compared my project with new laravel 5.4 project and found that this is commented out by default. I did that and my problem is fixed now.