# Remembering Users not working with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, cookies, remember-me

I have followed the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users) because 
I would like to use the `remember_me` token with Laravel. To verify it works I have a test `middleware` that do:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
return $next($request);
```

Later, on my test view I have:

```
{{@if (Auth::check())}}
Yeah!
{{@endif}}
```

So yes I am authenticated, but no I do not have any `remember_me` cookie set. I only see the session cookie.

I have also tried to use `Auth::User()->setRememberToken('foobar')`, but I got the same result: no `remember_me` cookie.

As advised from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232912/laravel-remember-me-not-working), I have set my session settings to:

```
'lifetime' => 10080,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

From this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696669/laravel-5-remember-me-not-working) I verified that `AuthenticateSession` middleware is enabled:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middlewares\Test::class, // Auth user 1 by id
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    ],
```

Of course if I do the following I get `false`:

```
dd(Auth::viaRemember());
```

Some other similar questions advise to use the `cookies` for the session. My `config('session')` looks like:

```
array:15 [▼
  "driver" => "cookie"
  "lifetime" => 10080
  "expire_on_close" => true
  "encrypt" => false
  "connection" => null
  "table" => "sessions"
  "store" => null
  "cookie" => "laravel_session"
  "path" => "/"
  "domain" => null
  "secure" => false
  "http_only" => true
  "same_site" => null
]
```

Comment: What about putting the Test Middleware after the StartSession or after both of the two middlewares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change session driver to use `cookie` Like:

.env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

OR

`app/config/session.php`

```
'driver' => 'cookie',
```

Also changed the order of middleware like:

```
'web' => [ 

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, 
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middlewares\Test::class, // Auth user 1 by id 
],
```

And last but not least, verify you have the middleware `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` enabled.

Comment: @nowox let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Hopefully you have used `web.php` to define the routes.

Comment: I think I have a clue, I may missing the `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse`.

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Latest version: 5.9

Comment: This middleware `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` was removed in `5.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195621/discussion-between-nowox-and-vikash-pathak).